# FLV cue points matching with PPT slides in real time

Tags: flash, video, powerpoint, flv

This is my challenge. I need to build a page that contains an FLV with 3 cue points. 2 mins in, 4 mins in, 6 mins in.

What I want to accomplish is make it so that if a user just plays the video at first, as soon as they hit the 2 mins mark in the video, a PPT slide on the page automatically updates to reflect that.

Is this at all possible without building the whole thing out in Flash?

Please let me know if I'm not being clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ca8.html

You can use Flash's ExternalInterface command to call a Javascript function that changes the PPT slide for you.  Note that communicating outside of Flash on the same page is generally really difficult and limited.

The other option you could do is create a cookie or change a variable in an XML file with Flash and have Javascript checking that variable every so many milliseconds for it to change and then changing the PPT.  This would be less efficient, but I've done something like this before and it works.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Do you know if it's also possible to somehow do this outside of flash if we wanted to target mobile devices? What if the video format is also different like an mp4 or webm. Is it still somehow possible?

Comment: Definitely, I think this should help: http://www.udjamaflip.com/javascript/105-html5-inline-mobile-video-playback-with-cuepoints